# (gLua) Derma not working. attempt to call method 'Close' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, runtime-error, garrys-mod

Error at function ContextClose()

And all derma menu not working

> attempt to call method 'Close' (a nil value)

I've create derma menu and it worked in garrysmod\lua folder,
then I moved flies to addon floder and it stopped working.

***cl_init.lua***

```lua
AddCSLuaFile("pbfhud.lua")
include("pbfhud.lua")
```

***pbfhud.lua***

```lua
AddCSLuaFile()

local statBarW, statBarH = ScrW() / 400, ScrH() / 10
local barW, barH = ScrW() / 4, ScrH() / 10
local btnW, btnH = ScrW() / 4, ScrH() / 20

surface.CreateFont( "NotDermaDefault", {
    font = "Arial",
    extended = false,
    size = 25,
    weight = 500,
    blursize = 0,
    scanlines = 0,
    antialias = true,
    underline = false,
    italic = false,
    strikeout = false,
    symbol = false,
    rotary = false,
    shadow = false,
    additive = false,
    outline = false,
} )
local function DrawInventorySlot(  )
    
end

local function DrawBar(x, y, w, h, color, text, val, name)
    local rtext = text .. ": " .. val
    local tW, tH = surface.GetTextSize(rtext)
    tH = tH / 2
    if (name == true) then
       tW = tW / 7
    end

    draw.RoundedBox(0, x, y, w, h, color)
    draw.SimpleText(rtext, "NotDermaDefault", barW / 2 - tW / 7, barH / 2 - tH + y, Color( 255, 255, 255, 255 ), TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER, TEXT_ALIGN_TOP)

end

function ContextOpen()
    gui.EnableScreenClicker( true )
    menu = vgui.Create("DFrame")
    menu:SetSize(ScrW(), ScrH() + 100)
    menu:ShowCloseButton(false)
    menu:SetTitle("")
    menu:Center()
    menu:SetDraggable(false)
    menu:SetBackgroundBlur(true)
    menu:SetMouseInputEnabled(true)
    menu.Paint = function()
        draw.RoundedBox(0, 0, 0, ScrW(), ScrH(), Color(0,0,0,100))
        local blur = Material("pp/blurscreen") 
        local function blurPanel(panel, amount) 
            local x, y = panel:LocalToScreen(0, 0) 
            local scrW, scrH = ScrW(), ScrH() 
            surface.SetDrawColor(255, 255, 255) 
            surface.SetMaterial(blur) 
            for i = 1, 6 do
                blur:SetFloat("$blur", (i / 3) * (amount or 6)) 
                blur:Recompute() 
                render.UpdateScreenEffectTexture() 
                surface.DrawTexturedRect(x * -1, y * -1, scrW, scrH) 
            end 
        end
        blurPanel(menu, 5)
        draw.RoundedBox(0, 0, 0, ScrW() / 4, ScrH(), Color(0,0,0,50))
        -- Stats
        DrawBar(0, 0, barW, barH, Color(235, 235, 235, 140), "Имя", LocalPlayer():getDarkRPVar("rpname"), true )
        DrawBar(0, statBarH, LocalPlayer():Health() * statBarW, barH, Color(255, 50, 43, 140), "Здоровье", LocalPlayer():Health(), false )
        DrawBar(0, statBarH * 2, LocalPlayer():Armor() * statBarW, barH, Color(43, 128, 255, 140), "Броня", LocalPlayer():Armor(), false )
        DrawBar(0, statBarH * 3, barW, barH, Color(255, 149, 43, 140), "Работа", LocalPlayer():getDarkRPVar("job"), false )
        DrawBar(0, statBarH * 4, barW, barH, Color(0, 138, 11, 140), "Зарплата", LocalPlayer():getDarkRPVar("salary"), false )

        -- Inventory
        draw.RoundedBox(0, barW, 0, ScrW() / 1.7, ScrH(), Color(0,0,0,50))

    end
        -- Buttons
    --fb = vgui.Create("DButton", menu)
    --fb:SetSize(btnW, btnH)
    --fb:SetPos(0, btnH * 12)
    --fb:SetText("")

end

function ContextClose()
    menu:Close()
    gui.EnableScreenClicker( false )
end

hook.Add ("OnContextMenuOpen", "Context", ContextOpen)
hook.Add ("OnContextMenuClose", "Context", ContextClose)
```

***Files location***

```
..addons\pbf_hud\lua\autorun\client\cl_init.lua
..addons\pbf_hud\lua\autorun\client\pbfhud.lua
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I used same identifiers for hooks. If you have same problem just change hook indentifier:

From:

```lua
hook.Add ("OnContextMenuOpen", "Context", ContextOpen)
hook.Add ("OnContextMenuClose", "Context", ContextClose)
```

To:

```lua
hook.Add ("OnContextMenuOpen", "Context_open", ContextOpen)
hook.Add ("OnContextMenuClose", "Context_close", ContextClose)
```

Comment: this... changes nothing, you still have different functions